# Convert .doc file into image and save in photo album

Tags: ios, iphone

I have downloaded the `.doc` file in document directory in `Objective-c`. But I want to save the image in the photo album of `iPhone`.
After some googling, I have found this:-

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myUIImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

I have `.doc` file, but how can I save it in the photo album using above code ?
Can anyone help me please?

**EDIT:**
I have now resolved my above problem. Now my only need is to get file from filepath then convert it into image and save that image into photo album.

Comment: I did not want to show. I have path of file, 

/Users/pksingh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/77C016C0-4A89-44C2-8616-4F32D1C2159C/data/Containers/Data/Application/62B48275-5D96-42FD-884A-25C309B75993/Documents/KG Classes PTM 24-May-2016.doc
Now my only need is get file from path -> convert into image-> and save into photo album..

Answer (score 0):

For opening pdf you can use UIWebview.

Pass your webview having doc which you want to capture.
Uiview can get uiwebview object.

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

by using this you will get an image and do your saving stuff like ,

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([image from method] ,nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) loadDocFile {
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 568.0f)];

    webView.delegate = self;

    NSURL *targetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyDoc" withExtension:@"doc"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate methods
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect originFrame = aWebView.frame;
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;

    UIImage *docImage = [self snapShot:aWebView];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(docImage, nil, nil, nil);
    aWebView.frame = originFrame;
}

// snapShot
- (UIImage*)snapShot:(UIView*)myView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.frame.size);
    [myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

Comment: I have implement but Not work, Actually my need not load on webview, my need only save doc file on download button in photoalbum in iPhone.